# Detect when user close window or presses back button (it's more complicated)

Tags: javascript, redirect, back

I would like to get a script that lets the user to navigate on your site and use the back button without any questions until it's the same domain. Otherwise ask the visitor if he really wants to leave the site.

I was able to write the part that take cares of the navigation. See here:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.links;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        });
};

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        location.assign('http://www.google.com');
    }, 0);
    return 'WAIT BEFORE YOU GO!\nClick "STAY ON THIS PAGE" and let me show you something!';
};
```

However I can't find any reference regarding the back button. If there was any event for this, I would approach the problem with something like this:

```
<on_back_button_event> = function () {
     if (document.referrer.split('/')[2] == location.hostname)
          window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

As I mentioned, I got stuck here. Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Using *setAttribute* for listeners is not advised, use [*addEventListener*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Also, not all A elements are links and AREA elements can cause navigation too. All links (A and AREA) in a document are available as [*document.links*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links).

Comment: @RobG document.links seems cleaner way to get what I need. But what's up with setAttribute? Anyways, I have made the changes to the question description.